# How to split elements separated by underscore in columns names and create

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following dataset. As you could see, the columns names are composed by three elements. I would like to separate each of the element separated by an underscore:

```
structure(list(post_name_mo_score = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526", 
"3433243juhy234_2323526"), minna_yout_qu_mai = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", 
"3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526"), tour_sima_ta_tup = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", 
"3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

in a way that all the first, second and thirs elements will go each of them under a new column **(i.e. column1 = post, minna, tour, column2 = name, yout, sima, column3 = mo, qu, ta)**

**Expected output**

```
clm1   clm2  clm3  score                    mai                      tup
post   name  mo    3433243juhy234_2323526   3433243juhy234_2323526 3433243juhy234_2323526 
minna  yout  qu    3433243juhy234_2323526   3433243juhy234_2323526 3433243juhy234_2323526 
tour   sima  ta    3433243juhy234_2323526   3433243juhy234_2323526 3433243juhy234_2323526
```

Can anyone suggest something functional for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr` does this well:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dat, everything(), values_to = "clm4") |>
  separate(name, into = c("clm1", "clm2", "clm3"), sep = "_")
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   clm1  clm2  clm3  clm4                  
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>                 
# 1 post  name  mo    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 2 minna yout  qu    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 3 tour  sima  ta    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 4 post  name  mo    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 5 minna yout  qu    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 6 tour  sima  ta    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 7 post  name  mo    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 8 minna yout  qu    3433243juhy234_2323526
# 9 tour  sima  ta    3433243juhy234_2323526
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(post_name_mo = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526"), minna_yout_qu = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526"), tour_sima_ta = c("3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526", "3433243juhy234_2323526")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks. There is just a small error in the expected output I have pointed out. I have updated it

Comment: Your updated data and expected output do not make sense: you have no `"mai"` associated with `"post_name_mo"`, _only_ `"minna_yout_qu"`.

Comment: yes, exactly. I would like just to separate the fourth elemnt (in this case, score, mai and tup) from the rest. Is not that possible to modify slightly the code on this purpose?

Comment: Umm, okay ... try `pivot_longer(dat, everything(), values_to = "clm4") |> separate(name, into = c("clm1", "clm2", "clm3", "something"), sep = "_") |> pivot_wider(id_cols = c(clm1, clm2, clm3), names_from = something, values_from = clm4) |> unnest(c(score, mai, tup))`

Comment: it isn't exactly what you have as "expected output" in your question, but then again I don't think the data supports _that_ layout